# Android tool tip show on on menu item

Tags: android

[image]

I want to display tool tip on menu item like this ,whenever the application loaded.! without any click ,it should show the tool tip.please help..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of libraries out there for this just search for `showcase view`.

 
Here's one of the most popular libraries: https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView